# method does not override or implement a method from a supertype error

Tags: java, interface, singleton, stack, abstract

I'm trying to design an undo/redo mechanism to my Chess game.. I decided to use stack data structure which is going to build on an ArrayList.. I also want that my UndoStack and RedoStack classes should be singleton.. However i'm getting

```
method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

pop() in UndoStack cannot implement pop() in IStackable
  return type Move is not compatible with cgas5.Move
  where Move is a type-variable:
    Move extends Object declared in class UndoStack
```

error..

Here is my IStackable interface:

```
package cgas5;


public interface IStackable {

    abstract public Move pop();

    abstract public void push(Move m);

}
```

and my UndoStack class

```
package cgas5;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UndoStack<Move> extends ArrayList<Move> implements IStackable {

    UndoStack undoStack;

    private UndoStack() {
        undoStack = new UndoStack();
    }

    public UndoStack getUndoStack() {
        if (undoStack == null) {
            undoStack = new UndoStack();
        }
        return undoStack;
    }

    @Override
    public Move pop() {
        Move m = get(size() - 1);
        remove(size() - 1);
        return m;

    }

    @Override
    public void push(Move m) {
        add(m);
    }
}
```

and if it's necessary my Move class:

```
package cgas5;

public class Move {
    private Piece pieceToMove;
    private Square currentSquare;
    private Square targetSquare;
    private Piece capturedPiece;
    private Piece promotedPiece;

    public Move(){

    } 

    public Move(Piece pieceToMove, Square currentSquare, Square targetSquare){
        this.pieceToMove = pieceToMove;
        this.currentSquare = currentSquare;
        this.targetSquare = targetSquare;
    }

    public Piece getPieceToMove() {
        return pieceToMove;
    }

    public void setPieceToMove(Piece pieceToMove) {
        this.pieceToMove = pieceToMove;
    }

    public Square getCurrentSquare() {
        return currentSquare;
    }

    public void setCurrentSquare(Square currentSquare) {
        this.currentSquare = currentSquare;
    }

    public Square getTargetSquare() {
        return targetSquare;
    }

    public void setTargetSquare(Square targetSquare) {
        this.targetSquare = targetSquare;
    }

    public Piece getCapturedPiece() {
        return capturedPiece;
    }

    public void setCapturedPiece(Piece capturedPiece) {
        this.capturedPiece = capturedPiece;
    }

    public Piece getPromotedPiece() {
        return promotedPiece;
    }

    public void setPromotedPiece(Piece promotedPiece) {
        this.promotedPiece = promotedPiece;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I don't think this makes sense: `public class UndoStack<Move>`

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: It makes sense as far as the compiler is concerned, but it's not what the OP wants...

Comment: In interface method declarations, you can omit both "abstract" and "public"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
public class UndoStack<Move> extends ArrayList<Move>
```

That's using `Move` as a *generic type parameter*, whereas really you don't want a generic type at all - you just want to use `Move` as the type *argument* for `ArrayList<E>`. You want:

```
public class UndoStack extends ArrayList<Move>
```

That should fix the problem - although personally I'd strongly recommend using composition instead of inheritance here. (In other words, make your `UndoStack` type *contain* an `ArrayList<Move>` - or something similar - rather than subclassing it.)

Additionally, this is never going to work:

```
UndoStack undoStack;

private UndoStack() {
    undoStack = new UndoStack();
}
```

That means that to create an `UndoStack`, you need to create another `UndoStack`... how do you expect that to happen? You'll currently get a stack overflow exception... why do you need the variable at all?